# How to disappear the overlay?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting small issue, once we click on button one modal popup displaying, but at the time of unload the overlay doesn't disappear.
I tried with below code, could anyone suggest me, whats the issue is ?

```
var popUpObj;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Button1").click(function(){
     popUpObj = window.open("http://www.w3schools.com/",
    "ModalPopUp",
    "toolbar=no," +
    "scrollbars=no," +
    "location=no," +
    "statusbar=no," +
    "menubar=no," +
    "resizable=0," +
    "width=100," +
    "height=100," +
    "left = 490," +
    "top=300"
    );
            popUpObj.focus();
            LoadModalDiv();
    });
});

  function LoadModalDiv() {
            var bcgDiv = document.getElementById("divBackground");
            bcgDiv.style.display = "block";
        }
 function HideModalDiv() {
            var bcgDiv = document.getElementById("divBackground");
            bcgDiv.style.display = "none";
        }
        function OnUnload() {
            if (false == popUpObj.closed) {
                popUpObj.close();
            }
         HideModalDiv();
        }
 window.onunload = OnUnload;
```

Comment: Where are you calling HideModalDiv?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are listening to the wrong `window.onunload` Instead of `window.onunload = OnUnload` try `popUpObj.onunload = OnUnload`. If you are wanting the overlay to disappear when the modal does then you have to listen for when the modal window unloads. By hooking into `window.unload` you are listening for when the parent window unloads not the modal. You can probably attempt to test if I'm write by watching careful if you close the parent window and see if the overlay flashes away briefly before the parent window closes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind unload event after popUpObj initialize.

```
    $("#Button1").click(function(){
     popUpObj = window.open("page2.html",
    "ModalPopUp",
    "toolbar=no," +
    "scrollbars=no," +
    "location=no," +
    "statusbar=no," +
    "menubar=no," +
    "resizable=0," +
    "width=100," +
    "height=100," +
    "left = 490," +
    "top=300"
    );
            popUpObj.focus();
            LoadModalDiv();
            popUpObj.onunload = window.OnUnload;
    });
```

The above code doesn't work if you call another domain like  "**window.open('google.com')**";........... else it only works if the URL same as parent (Same domain).  And this is the main problem.